# degree of generator polynomial $m(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

Suppose $Q$ is cyclic $(h,q)$ code over $F_u$ such that $\gcd(h,u) = 1$.
Prove that degree of the generator polynomial $m(x)$ of $Q$ is $h - q$.

Why do we need the condition $\gcd(h,u) = 1$ ?

Any ideas?

Comment: What dreadfully nonstandard notation! What book are you reading? The reason for the condition $\gcd(h,u) = 1$ is that the standard theory of cyclic codes assumes that there exists a $h$-th root of unity in the finite field $F_u$ or some extension field of $F_u$.  But, $u = p^m$ for some prime $p$ and positive integer $m$, and in a field of characteristic $p$, no element can have multiplicative order that is a multiple of $p$. Thus, $\gcd(h,u) = 1$ means we are considering the standard theory. Without this restriction, each theorem would need to include special cases for codes for which $p|h$.

Comment: what about the actual problem of degree of m(x) to be h - q?